# Contacts not appearing in a smart group

Tags: smartgroups

We have a smart group which returns 1,521 records.  One contact which ought to be appearing in it isn't.  When I go in to the smar group settings there is an unfinished selection line, when I delete this the search then gives 1,552 records, including the one that we saw was missing.  I then take the action of updating the smart group but when I go back into the manage groups and click on contacts it is once more back at 1,521 with the one we want missing.  It is very possible that there is a step that I should be taking which I am not.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am running Civicrm 5.13.4

Comment: Can you confirm that in Scheduled Jobs, you have 'Rebuild Smart Groups Cache' set to run?  You can find it in Administer/System Settings/Scheduled Jobs.

Comment: perhaps add a screenshot of the 'results' bit from the Adv Search so the 'unfinished selection line' makes more sense. also, does this involve contact sub-types?